# obect-fit: cover not working on elements with position: fixed

Tags: html, css

I need some kind of parallex effect on an image. So I need the image to cover the area and be fixed at the same time.

Look at my Example:
https://codepen.io/markus-burda/pen/poQWRRj

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}

.image {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000" />
</div>
```

When I remove the `position: fixed;` property, the `object-fit: cover` works properly.

Anyone a solution?

Image should be fixed and the the image should expand correctly inside the wrapper, how to expect from object-fit: cover;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: fixed;` with `width` and `height` of `100%` doesn't inherit its parent's dimentions.

However if the parent of it has width and height assigned explicitly, you may use value of `inherit` to inherit its dimention.

```css
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}

.image {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* inherit width and height from parent */
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

position fixed will not inherit height width from parent element. you'll need to give specific height width to image element.

```css
.image {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 600px;
}
```